# Need Solution on NicEditor - How can I add a custom select options?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, wysiwyg

I am using NICInline Editor, sample is here - http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=4

How can I add my custom Options to this editor? so that when I select an option its Value is inserted exactly at the cursor point of the Editor Instance.

Question: I need to add these custom options to be added to the Editor?

```
<select name="fruit" id="fruit">
    <option value="mango">mango</option>
    <option value="apple">apple</option>
</select>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I reckon like many editor you need to create a plugin for it, there is documentation on their website, this page seems to have the information you need to get started: http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/516/Creating%20a%20Plugin

Comment: Hi, I did go through the manual and i could build a options in WYSIWYG editor but iam experiencing one problem. The values i select are not inserting in the Content. Here is my work: http://tiny.cc/rb_testeditor  Can any one give me correct solution to fix this problem? Please try to insert a fruit in the content by using this editor.